# Make input value depend on `select option` selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, event-handling

Basically if `male` is selected, make the `input` named `pronoun` have a value of `his`. Else, make the `input` named `pronoun` have a value of `her`.

```
<select name="sex">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="pronoun" value="" placeholder="pronoun" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("select").change(function() {
   if($(this).val() == 'male'){
      $('input[name=pronoun]').val('his')
   }
   else{
      $('input[name=pronoun]').val('her')
    }
});
```

or

```
$("select").change(function() {
    $('input[name=pronoun]').val(($(this).val() == 'male') ? 'his' : 'her');
}).change();
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LLfonLqp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use *jQuery* -

```
var value = $('select[name="sex"]').val() == 'male' ? 'his' : 'her';
$('input[name="pronoun"]').val(value); // Set the value by default

$('select[name="sex"]').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'male') {
        $('input[name="pronoun"]').val('his');
    } else {
        $('input[name="pronoun"]').val('her');
    }
})
```

[Check it here](https://jsfiddle.net/9jzyLf7q/)

Answer (score 0):

use `change()` event

```
$("select[name=sex]").change(function () {
    $('input[name=pronoun]').val((this.value == 'male') ? "His" : "Her")
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rdL8jgbt/)**

Answer (score 0):

Html Code :

```
<select  name="sex" class="test">
  <option value="male">Male</option>
  <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="pronoun" class="pronoun" value="" placeholder="pronoun"/>
```

Jquery Code :

```
<script>
$('.test').on('change', function() {
var value =this.value;
    if(value == 'male')
    {
        $('.pronoun').val('his');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.pronoun').val('her');
    }
});
</script>
```

please check it

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an `id` value and use jQuery's selector and event handler to do what you want.

```
<select id="sex" name="sex">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
<input id="pronoun" type="text" name="pronoun" value="" placeholder="pronoun" />

<script>
$('#sex').change(function() {
    $('#pronoun').val($(this).val() == 'female' ? 'her' : 'his');
});
$('#sex').change();
</script>
```